# Next JS getInitialProps Axios.Get Dynamic API Endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, next.js

I have a next.js app that makes API calls to a django server. The issue I'm having now is calling dynamic content with getInitialProps. Please see the url examples below. Basically, how would I pull a primary key dynamically in getinitialprops.

Example:

> .herokuapp.com/api/v2/pages/1/?type=projects.ProjectsPage&fields=* vs
>   .herokuapp.com/api/v2/pages/2/?type=projects.ProjectsPage&fields=*

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const resProjects = await axios.get(`...herokuapp.com/api/v2/pages/PK/?type=projects.ProjectsPage&fields=*`);
        return {
            data: data
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your API endpoint seems odd, with no protocol (http, https). Please, clarify where is used your primary key, in the API call, in the HTTP query ? Put an real URL example of how your API is really called

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working on a dynamic route, you have access to that info through ctx. For example, at the /projects/[id] page you can access id as shown below.

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const id = ctx.query.id;
    //make the api call using id
}
```

this is explained here: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: Thank you, Devlyn Dorfer! That's exactly what I needed.